# AWS CLI for searching a file in s3 bucket

Tags: aws-cli

I want to search for a file name abc.zip in s3 buckets and there are nearly 60 buckets and each buckets have 2 to 3 levels subdirectories or folders .I tried to perform search using AWS CLI commands and below are the commands which i tried but even though the file is existing in the bucket.The results are not being displayed for the file.

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket bucketname --region ca-central-1 \
    --recursive --query "Contents[?contains(Key, 'abc.zip')]"

aws s3 ls --summarize --human-readable --recursive bucketname \
    --region ca-central-1 | egrep 'abc.zip'
```

For all the above commands execution i dont see the filename in command line and when i manually check the bucket the file exists.
Is there any way i can find the file.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Hmm. 
I used your command from #1 without "--recursive" because this throws `Unknown options: --recursive`. The file I was searching for is on the second level of the bucket and it was found. `--region` is also not used.

My guess is you are using some old version of AWS client or pointing to an incorrect bucket.
My working command:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket XXXXX --query "Contents[?contains(Key, 'animate.css')]"

[
{
    "LastModified": "2015-06-14T23:29:03.000Z",
    "ETag": "\"e5612f9c5bc799b8b129e9200574dfd2\"",
    "StorageClass": "STANDARD",
    "Key": "css/animate.css",
    "Owner": {
        "DisplayName": "XXXX",
        "ID": "XXXX"
    },
    "Size": 78032
}
]
```

If you decide to upgrade your CLI client: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/tree/master
Current version is `awscli-1.15.77` which you may check by `aws --version`.

Comment: @aish-mahesh if the answer works for you could you make it accepted answer? 
Also please share information on how you solved your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response it worked for me after upgrading the version and executing the same command and as you said --region was not required. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 15):

I tried in the following way

```
aws s3 ls s3://Bucket1/folder1/2019/ --recursive |grep filename.csv
```

This outputs the actual path where the file exists

```
2019-04-05 01:18:35     111111 folder1/2019/03/20/filename.csv
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 9):

I know this is ancient, but I found a way to do this without piping text to grep...

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket myBucket --prefix 'myFolder' \
--query "Contents[*]|[?ends_with(Key,'jpg')].[Key]"
```

Comment: Ancient or not, you helped a man under desperation. Thanks

Comment: `--prefix` is a game changer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think previous answers are correct but if you want make this, bucket agnostic, then you can use the below script all you have to do is change the variable value (search_value) on the first line to what you
are searching for and add your id and secret:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=your_key; export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=your_secret;
search_value="3ds"
my_array=( `aws s3api list-buckets --query "Buckets[].Name"|grep \"  |sed 's/\"//g'|sed 's/\,//g'` )
my_array_length=${#my_array[@]}
for element in "${my_array[@]}"
do
   echo "----- ${element}"
   aws s3 ls s3://"${element}" --recursive  |grep -i $search_value 
done
```

- Warning....it will search every single bucket in your account so be prepared for a long search....
- It does pattern search so it will find any words that contains the value
- Lastly this is case insensitive search ... (you can disable that by removing -i from grep line)
  done